# Windows 7 + Soniwall NSA3500 Site to site vpn

Tags: windows, vpn, sonicwall, site-to-site-vpn

How can I configure the site-to-site VPN connection using Windows 7 on one side and Sonicwal NSA3500 on another side?

I know how to configure the Sonicwall. I've basically done VPN configurations using 2 routers, but I dont know how to do it using Windows 7, with software VPN. Is there any additional application needs to be downloaded for Windows 7, to make it work with IPSec? or Windows 7 has some built-in features which needs to be enabled?

I want some free software, or better using the built-in features of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is a client OS, hence you can't really use it to establish a site to site VPN. Well, you probably can do something, but no vendor will support it.

Anyway, what you're after is known as a remote access VPN, point to site or client to site. You'll have to configure your SonicWall for that purpose and use its [VPN client](https://support.software.dell.com/sonicwall-global-vpn-client/) on your Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sonicwall makes a VPN client for PCs - http://help.mysonicwall.com/applications/vpnclient/

Site-to-Site generally refers to a connection between two dedicated VPN routers.

Comment: Thx for reply. I have only 50 licenses for Global VPN, and once I reach it I cant connect anymore, as we are not going to purchase additional licenses. Is there any other free software to make a point-to-site connection to sonicwall?